# How do i connect 5 data tables like this on tibco spotfire

Tags: spotfire

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzrjQ.jpg)

Light blue are the keys i use to connect

I can only connect to the main data table but cannot do second tier connections like what i drew out

Please help me i am at a loss. Cant seem to find other help online

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the main table MCR column as keys for two secondary tables. Then you want to use the ID column from the two secondary tables (joined by MCR) as key for two tertiary tables.

The ID joins could get a little less straight forward. The second MCR join will make an ID(2) column. It will be important to know which ID column comes from which secondary table.

Are the tables being generated by an information link or are you importing from a other source (excel, clipboard copy,... Etc)

1. Bring in primary table
2. Bring in each secondary table (with MCRcolumn match only)
3. Note which secondary table came in first as it will add the ID column. The other secondary table will add an ID(2)
4. Bring in tertiary columns based on ID or ID(2)